Контейнер PHP FPM в Docker не может скачатся
Контейнер - php 8.1-fpm не может никак закачать пакеты нужные ему, типо не может подключиться к интернету, я уже чуть ли не весь гугл испробовал
Пишет что типо в файле cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
нужно прописать dns
{
    "dns": ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"]
}

Но я это делаю и не помогает вообще...
Вот такое пишет очень долго

Все контейнеры и фронта и бд и nginx отлично скачиваются, а этот php-8.1-fpm не может.
Причем прикол в том что на компе с виндой докер отлично запускает этот проект. На компе с линуксом докер отлично запускает этот проект. А вот на серевере уже никак не хочет.
Вот по такой ошибке отваливается в конце

Я понимаю что проблема с сетью в Docker'e, но как это решить никак не пойму. Буду рад любой помощи, спасибо!

vpn может какой-то там

Суть заключалась в том что для руссих серваков заблокированы репозитории дебиана и убунту, причем заблокированы так,что заблокированы IP русских VPS'ок, то есть, на локале всё будет ок, а на рус ВПСке не запустит. Решения оказалось два:

Если хотите остаться на РУС ВПСке, то можно настроить зеркала яндеса, у них есть ссылки на дебиан и убунту - ссылка.
Но минус этого метода в том, что после настройки зеркал всё скачалось, а когда я начал качать пакеты composer'a, то всё опять встало и я уже не имел желания искать зеркала для этого или форкать каждый пакет.

Решение, к которому я прибегнул - просто арендовать европейскую ВПСку, и не думать о дальнейших проблемах. Лучше всего брать Литву или Латвию, т.к. у них низкий пинг для РФ


